# Mapping not found on Easyadmin with a relation field and Vich

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, vichuploaderbundle, symfony6

I'm looking to refactor some code to avoid repetition ;) Bundles used:

- symfony 6.0.7
- vich/uploader-bundle 1.19
- easycorp/easyadmin-bundle 4.1.1

I have a Content entity where all content types are defined. The MyImage property is a OneToOne relationship to an Image utility entity so as not to repeat the code.

When I try to display the edit (or create) page of a Page, the following error is raised: Mapping not found for field " myImage_image".

Here are the files in question.

The Content entity:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Content;

use App\Entity\Media\Image;
use App\Repository\Content\ContentRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ContentRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'content')]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'type', type: 'string')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    'page' => Page::class,
    // ...
])]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
abstract class Content
{
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    // ...

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Image::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Image $myImage;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myImage = new Image();
    }
    
    // ...

    public function getMyImage(): Image
    {
        return $this->myImage;
    }

    public function setMyImage(Image $myImage): self
    {
        $this->myImage = $myImage;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Image entity:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Media;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\Timestampable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
class Image
{
    use Timestampable;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'content', fileNameProperty: 'imageName')]
    private ?File $image;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $imageName;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param  int|null  $id
     */
    public function setId(?int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getImage(): ?File
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @param $image
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setImage($image): self
    {
        // VERY IMPORTANT:
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using Doctrine,
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        if ($image) {
            // if 'updatedAt' is not defined in your entity, use another property
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string|null  $imageName
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setImageName(?string $imageName): self
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The Vich config:

```yaml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    metadata:
        type: attribute
    mappings:
        content:
            uri_prefix: /uploads/content
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/content'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
            directory_namer:
                service: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\CurrentDateTimeDirectoryNamer
                options:
                    date_time_format: 'Y' # will create directory "2018/23/09" for curent date "2018-09-23"
                    date_time_property: createdAt # see above example
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

I'm sure it's a silly error but I can't seem to catch it.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**

The CRUD Controller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Content;

use App\Entity\Content\Page;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\Field;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FormField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextareaField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class PageCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Page::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        // ...

        yield Field::new('myImage.image')->setFormType(VichImageType::class);

            // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an `ImageType` and used it in CRUD Controller:

```php
// ...
     yield Field::new('myImage.image', false)->setFormType(ImageType::class);
// ...
```